# C# - Refactor Dictionary Helper

Tags: c#, dictionary, refactoring

I have the following helper to check if dictionary key exists. This works fine for a string string type dictionary

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName");

public static TU GetValue<T, TU>(this Dictionary<T, TU> dict, T key) where TU : class
{
    TU val;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out val);
    return val;
}
```

How do I refactor it so that if I have a dictionary with a list I want to check if key exist and if it does the get the first item in the list e.g:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//populate the dictionary...

// Call to get first item from dictionary using key
myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName")[0]
```

I want to use it in razor as follows:

```
  <span >@myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName")[0]</span>
```

Comment: It already *does* do what you say you want it to do.

Comment: @Servy no it throws exception if key doesnt exist becuase the value type is a list

Comment: You said that if the key has a value it should give it to you, and have said nothing about what it should do if there is no value, so again, the code you have provided already does exactly what you've said it needs to do.

Comment: Just call myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName").FirstOrDefault() instead when you know you're dealing with a dictionary that has an enumerable of values per key, or write a separate extension method per Sergey's answer. I don't think there is a really sensible way to handle both enumerables and non-enumerables in the same function, certainly not without knowing what to cast the individual objects within the enumerables to.

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` *is* a "normal key value type dictionary." The values are lists of strings.

Comment: @Trioj `myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName").FirstOrDefault()` will not work. you will get error Value cannot be null if the dictionary is empty.

Comment: Then validate your code. If the dictionary is null or empty, don’t call GetValue or have it return an empty string or something. Sergey has a totally workable answer as well. Also FirstOrDefault() doesn’t throw exception if collection is empty, so not exactly sure what you’re talking about upon further reflection.

Comment: @adam78 Again, you haven't said what you *want* to do when the key doesn't exist, you've just said what you want to do when the key *does* exist.

Comment: @Servy What's not normal about it? I don't know. If something wasn't normal I would have said, " 
A Dictionary<string, List<string>> is *not* a "normal key value type dictionary."

Comment: @ScottHannen Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: If you’re worried about the object you’d be calling FirstOrDefault() on being null, then you’d obviously just null check it before calling the method.

Comment: @Trioj I dont want to start checking the object for null etc. I want to use it in razor as is, if the dictionary has a key then I want to get the first Item in the list. A more real world example could be an errors list for a field. Sergeys code is throwing an error.

Comment: @Servy if there is no value then nothing should be output - see my edit.

Comment: @adam78 You may need to provide more of a code sample if his code is throwing an error for you. It works fine for me. I also see very little reason why you can't just do something like myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName")?.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty unless you are using an earlier framework version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about the reason for the error message is incorrect: the problem isn't that you are returning a `List<string>` from `GetValue`, the problem is you are trying to index the null value returned when the key is not found.

You need to verify your result is not null:

```
<span>@(myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName") != null ? myDictionary.GetValue("FirstName")[0] : null)</span>
```

in which case the original function would seem more useful:

```
<span>@(myDictionary.TryGetValue("FirstName", out var val) ? val[0] : null)</span>
```

You could modify your function to return an empty collection but then you would get an index out of range error. I see no reasonable return object to allow you to index by an arbitrary value without error. Otherwise you must create a second function to handle indexable types, which leads you to the other answer (which I see was deleted so putting in here):

```
public static TU GetFirstValue<T, TU>(this Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<TU>> dict, T key) {
    IEnumerable<TU> val;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out val);

    return (val == null ? default(TU) : val.First());
}
```

You could rename the original function as GetFirstValue as well, and the compiler would use whichever was appropriate.